# C++ design pattern suggestion

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to do following, I am writing Graph library. I want my class should be template.

```
template < typename T>
class Graph
{
}
```

This Graph class works on another `class Vertex`

How should I design this `Vertex` class so that any of my team members can use and I do not have to change my implementation in `class Graph`

Basically I want this `Vertex` class to provide couple of member function like `getWeight`,   `getvisited`,`setvisited`

So as long as client have these function in there class `Graph` class can be used as it is

Comment: Have you looked at Boost Graph? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph

Comment: You mean `Graph<T>` will use a specific class `Vertex` as a member or method parameter? Or you mean `Graph<Vertex>` should be allowed as long as `Vertex` supplies certain interface methods?

Comment: Yes aschepler, This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Graph<Vertex> should be allowed.

Comment: So where exactly is the problem? Your class will be able to work with every vertex class which provides all methods used by your class, so it should work by simply making Graph a template with the vertextype as parameter

Comment: I am planning to use stl map in Graph class, I want Graph Template type should always implement certain number of interfaces and some operators say <

Comment: @Avinash: A `map< Vertex*, Vertex* >` only allows one edge per vertex. `multimap` would be better… in that case you effectively have objects for both edges and vertices, which isn't memory efficient. Also, looking up the edges connected to a vertex becomes O(log N) time where it should be O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Typically a graph class doesn't do much because all the data is in the vertices or edges (depending which is represented by objects — it sounds like you want vertex objects).

So, you might have

```
template< typename T >
struct Vertex {
    bool visited;
    T data;

    vector< Vertex * > edges;

    size_t getWeight() const { return edges.size(); }

    bool getvisited() const { return visited; }
    void setvisited( bool v ) { visited = v; }
};
```

You might want the graph glass to own all the vertices, and prevent problems with disconnection or cycles when trying to destroy it.

```
template< typename T >
struct Graph {
    typedef Vertex< T > vertex_t;
    deque< vertex_t > vertices;

    vertex_t &get_vertex() {
        return * vertices.insert( vertices.end(), vertex_t() );
    }
};
```

… and make the constructors of `Vertex` private, and Graph its `friend`, to make `Graph` the only way of obtaining vertices.

Answer (score 0):

The following scenarios below may help when defining the Vertex interface.  It will give you the ability to define signatures up front so that Graph is able to compile as well as let users extend Vertex for their needs through inheritance (if that is one of your goals).

```
// Interface only (i.e. pure virtual). The user must implement this method   
// but the signature is defined up front so Graph able to call it.  
class Vertex {
  public:
  virtual int getWeight() = 0;   
};

// Interface with a default implementation (i.e. virtual).  The default 
// implementation is provided by you but the user can override the 
// implementation if needed.
class Vertex {
  public:
  virtual int getWeight();
};

// Interface has a required implementation (i.e. non-virtual).  The user 
// should not override your implementation.
class Vertex {
  public:
  int getWeight();
};
```